# Excel VBA, can pass activecell.value to object but not a variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using some code i harvested from the internet to read the metadata from files in a folder.

To create the shell folder object i need to pass the path to the shell app object.

I am using the following code:

```
Sub ReadMetadata()
Dim iShell
Dim iDir
Dim iFile As Variant
Dim RowEntry As Double

RF_FolderToRead = "C:\test"

Set iShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

'ActiveCell.Value = RF_FolderToRead

Set iDir = iShell.Namespace(RF_FolderToRead)
'Set iDir = iShell.Namespace(ActiveCell.Value)

If iDir Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Folder Not Found"
    Set iShell = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End If

RowEntry = 1

For Each iFile In iDir.Items
   If Right(iFile.Name, 3) = "m4a" Or Right(iFile.Name, 3) = "mp3" Then
        
        DoEvents
    
    ArtistName = iDir.GetDetailsOf(iFile, 20)
    TrackName = iDir.GetDetailsOf(iFile, 21)
    
        With ActiveSheet
            .Cells(RowEntry, ActiveCell.Column).Value = ArtistName
            .Cells(RowEntry, ActiveCell.Column + 1).Value = TrackName
        End With
        
        RowEntry = RowEntry + 1

    End If
Next iFile



Set iShell = Nothing
Set iDir = Nothing
Set iFile = Nothing
End Sub
```

The above code does not set the iDir Object, and does not throw an error, however uncommenting the line which sets activecell.value to the RF_FolderToRead, and that which then passes activecell.value to iShell works fine.

Can anyone reproduce this strange behaviour, or suggest a reason and/or a workaround that does not involve writing to a cell first?

Any and all assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: No problems here maybe you could try:  Dim RF_FolderToRead As Variant or double Parentheses : iShell.Namespace((RF_FolderToRead))

Comment: @EvR Cool Technique! Can you explain what is happening when doubling the parentheses?

Comment: It will make it a String and not a String-Variable, I expect Cstr(RF_FolderToRead) will work also

Comment: How and where is `RF_FolderToRead` declared?  Shell methods typically don't like `String` arguments - typically you would declare any variables passed to Shell as `Variant`

Comment: Thanks EvR, that works a treat.  Not much experience with Shell methods but it's something i'll bear in mind for the future.

Comment: And Tim, the variable was actually declared as a public string in the module. Thanks also for your input.